# Website Launch - 500.19 Error

Tags: http, http-status-code-503

I've been trying to deploy my new website to which I am having incredible difficulty. The website was built on a 32bit machine, deploying on 64bit server. The website connects to an Access Database (not sure if this is rellevant).

Firstly, I stumbled across a 503 error with the pool stopping. After googling, many pointed towards EXPPW.dll was causing the issue and many posts suggest adding 'preCondition="bitness64" in the applicationHost file. I tried this but now I get a 500.19 error.

I thought it might be my web.config file that is causing this but have ruled that out as I cleared it out and still receive the error. I've googled this to death but cannot find the answer!

Hope you can help.

Lewis

Comment: What webserver? iis? apache? nginx? with iis, 500.19 can mean malformed xml in web.config. Trying from the server directly should give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: Hi Kevin - thanks for replying. Windows Server 2012, IIS 8, running from the server doesn't give much info: Error Code=0x800700c1, Handler =  PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0; XML has been emptied out from web.config to no avail! Stuck!

Comment: the error code can be useful. For example, it points to this description from Microsoft: *"This problem can occur if the bitness of the specified module is different than that of the application pool hosting the application. For example, you are attempting to load a 32-bit component into a 64-bit application pool. This problem may also occur if the specified module is corrupted."* https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055

Comment: hmmm, this error only occurs when I add preCondition="bitness64" to the EXPPW.dll. If I take this out, I then get a 503 error which the event log points to EXPPW.dll: exppw.dll could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a x86 processor architecture. So, If I make the change to bitness like posts on SO suggest, I then get this 500.19 error.

Comment: Definitely sounds like some kind of conflict between 32bit and 64bit. like, you're trying to run a 32bit module/application in a 64bit application pool. I'm not too familiar with this area as everything I do is 64bit so i never have to deal with these issues.

Comment: Really appreciate your help Kevin. Ok, so  I'm building on 32bit using Visual Studios. Could publishing it as a 64bit application work?

Comment: I have no idea, i don't work with visual studio. Maybe someone else will come along.